# Как скопировать репозиторий в тот же аккаунт на Bitbucket, не скачивая на компьютер?

Tags: git, bitbucket

Вопрос в заголовке.

Как это сделать? У меня интернет медленный и глючный.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно воспользоваться командой <kbd>Import</kbd> из своего же аккаунта, поставить галочку <kbd>Use Authorization</kbd> (если установлен пароль), ввести заново учётные данные и нажать <kbd>Ok</kbd>. Он сам всё сделает.